# Acquiring pool connections in Python Gino (async)

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg, gino

I'm using Postgres, Python3.7 with `asyncio` + `asyncpg` + `gino` (ORM-ish) + `aiohttp` (routing, web responses).

I created a small postgres table `users` in my database `testdb` and inserted a single row:

```
testdb=# select * from users;
 id | nickname
----+----------
  1 | fantix
```

I'm trying to set up my database such that I can make use of the ORM within routes as requests come in.

```py
import time
import asyncio
import gino

DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

db = gino.Gino()

class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  nickname = db.Column(db.Unicode(), default='noname')

kwargs = dict(
  min_size=10,
  max_size=100,
  max_queries=1000,
  max_inactive_connection_lifetime=60 * 5,
  echo=True
)

async def test_engine_implicit():
  await db.set_bind(DATABASE_URL, **kwargs)
  return await User.query.gino.all()      # this works

async def test_engine_explicit():
  engine = await gino.create_engine(DATABASE_URL, **kwargs)
  db.bind = engine
  async with engine.acquire() as conn:
    return await conn.all(User.select())  # this doesn't work!

users = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_engine_implicit())
print(f'implicit query: {users}')

users = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_engine_explicit())
print(f'explicit query: {users}')
```

The output is:

```
web_1    | INFO gino.engine._SAEngine SELECT users.id, users.nickname FROM users
web_1    | INFO gino.engine._SAEngine ()
web_1    | implicit query: [<db.User object at 0x7fc57be42410>]
web_1    | INFO gino.engine._SAEngine SELECT
web_1    | INFO gino.engine._SAEngine ()
web_1    | explicit query: [()]
```

which is strange. The "explicit" code essentially runs a bare `SELECT` against the database, which is useless.

I can't find in the documentation a way to both 1) use the ORM, and 2) explicitly check out connections from the pool.

Questions I have:

1. Does `await User.query.gino.all()` check out a connection from the pool? How is it released?
2. How would I wrap queries in a transaction? I am uneasy that I am not able to explicitly control when / where I acquire a connection from the pool, and how I release it.

I'd essentially like the explicitness of the style in `test_engine_explicit()` to work with Gino, but perhaps I'm just not understanding how the Gino ORM works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used GINO before, but after a quick look into the code:

1. GINO connection simply [executes provided clause as is](https://github.com/fantix/gino/blob/77e19f58e4295729937a46996c0630020b29b9a3/gino/engine.py#L312). Thus, if you provide bare `User.select()`, then it adds nothing to that.
2. If you want to achieve the same as using `User.query.gino.all()`, but maintaining connection yourself, then you could [follow the docs](http://gino.fantix.pro/en/latest/tutorial.html#retrieve) and use `User.query` instead of plain `User.select()`:

```py
async with engine.acquire() as conn:
    return await conn.all(User.query)
```

Just tested and it works fine for me.

Regarding the connections pool, I am not sure that I got the question correctly, but `Engine.acquire` [creates a reusable connection by default](https://github.com/fantix/gino/blob/77e19f58e4295729937a46996c0630020b29b9a3/gino/engine.py#L619) and then it is added to the pool, which is actually a stack:

> ```
>    :param reusable: Mark this connection as reusable or otherwise. This
>       has no effect if it is a reusing connection. All reusable connections
>       are placed in a stack, any reusing acquire operation will always
>       reuse the top (latest) reusable connection. One reusable connection
>       may be reused by several reusing connections - they all share one
>       same underlying connection. Acquiring a connection with
>       ``reusable=False`` and ``reusing=False`` makes it a cleanly isolated
>       connection which is only referenced once here.
> ```

There is also a [manual transaction control](http://gino.fantix.pro/en/latest/transaction.html#manual-control) in GINO, so e.g. you can create a non-reusable, non-reuse connection and control transaction flow manually:

```py
async with engine.acquire(reuse=False, reusable=False) as conn: 
     tx = await conn.transaction() 
     try: 
          await conn.status("INSERT INTO users(nickname) VALUES('e')") 
          await tx.commit() 
     except Exception: 
          await tx.rollback() 
          raise
```

As for connection release, I cannot find any evidence that GINO releases connections itself. I guess that pool is maintained by SQLAlchemy core.

I definitely have not answered your questions directly, but hope it will help you somehow.